# Is the TSI index now enabled by default in influxdb 1.7.x?

Tags: influxdb

The [upgrade guide](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/administration/upgrading/#upgrading-influxdb-1-3-1-4-no-tsi-preview-to-1-7-x-tsi-enabled) vs. the [release notes](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/about_the_project/releasenotes-changelog/#time-series-index-tsi-query-performance-and-throughputs-improvements) for InfluxDB 1.7.x are confusing to me with regards to the TSI feature (Time Series Index).

The **upgrade guide** [says](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/administration/upgrading/#upgrading-influxdb-1-3-1-4-no-tsi-preview-to-1-7-x-tsi-enabled) (similar as previously for 1.6):

> ***Note:*** For the InfluxDB 1.7 release, the default continues to use TSM-based shards as in earlier versions, with in-memory indexes.

However, the **release notes** contain the following [phrasing](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/about_the_project/releasenotes-changelog/#time-series-index-tsi-query-performance-and-throughputs-improvements):

> **To take advantage of these improvements**:
>
> - Rebuild your indexes or wait for a TSI compaction of your indexes, at which point the new TSI format will be applied.
> - Hot shards and new shards immediately use the new TSI format.

So, my questions are: (after upgrading from pre-TSI InfluxDB installation)

- do I still need to manually set `INFLUXDB_DATA_INDEX_VERSION=tsi1` in config, or is it default now?
- do I have to run the poorly documented `influx_inspect buildtsi` command to do the upgrade from TSM to TSI, or can I just wait for a while (how long?) doing nothing special, and the migration will eventually be automatically & transparently completed in the background without my active intervention?

Comment: Your question is only the 5th one in the history of the site about influxdb, and your new tag has no followers.  Good luck on this one, but SU doesn't appear to have much of a concentration of subject matter experts.  Any chance the company has a support forum, any any kind of tech support?

Comment: As @fixer1234 suggested, here's the canonical Q&A for InfluxData: https://community.influxdata.com/